# replace array(), to current logged user

Tags: wordpress, plugins

please advise, i need to replace 
'default'      => array(),  in to a current logged user in Wordpress

in custom post now, must select the user Manually

```
<?php

return array(
    'author' => array(
        'label'        => __('Author', 'ait-toolkit'),
        'type'         => 'select-dynamic',
        'dataFunction' => 'AitItemCpt::fillAuthorMetabox',
        'default'      => 'login',
        'capabilities' => true,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, you could try using `current_user` global variable. It's an instance of WP_User class.

```
global $current_user;
return array(
    'author' => array(
        'label' => __('Author', 'ait-toolkit'),
        'type' => 'select-dynamic',
        'dataFunction' => 'AitItemCpt::fillAuthorMetabox',
        'default' => $current_user, //$current_user->ID for example. Or whatever else you need
        'capabilities' => true,
    )
);
```

Bit unclear what exactly you want to achieve though

Comment: Hi,thank you for help. If i add new post, the current user i selected and saved. Now i have imported dummy data via XML import, and i need after editing the post, save the current logged user.
screens: 
https://ibb.co/hrGUGF
https://ibb.co/fXZGwF